# Importing commonJS module via ES6 import, Property does not exist on type 'typeof import

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I have the following typescript modules,

server.ts

```
// server.ts
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

module.exports = {
  App: app,
};
```

index.ts

```
// index.ts
import * as App from './server';
console.log(App.App);
```

On compiling the following program I get the following error.
Property 'App' does not exist on type 'typeof import("src/server")'

Conceptually why is it failing?

Few points which are especially confusing are, on printing just the imported server.js like

```
// alternate server.ts
import * as App from './server';

console.log(App);
```

I get the output express App structure in the logs, like below

```
{
  App: [Getter],
  default: {
    App: [Function: app] EventEmitter {
      emit: [Function: emit],
      addListener: [Function: addListener],
      on: [Function: addListener],
      ...
      get: [Function],
      notify: [Function],
      options: [Function],
      patch: [Function],
      post: [Function],
      ...
      listen: [Function: listen],
      request: [IncomingMessage],
      response: [ServerResponse],
      ...
      locals: [Object: null prototype],
      mountpath: '/',
      _router: [Function]
    }
  }
}
```

If it is present in the structure on console.log why am I not able to access the same via code.

Comment: Don't mix ES6 import with commonjs export.

Comment: Try import { default as App } from './server';

Comment: @Bergi in case I am consuming libraries using both commonjs and ES6 modules, I will face this issue at some point in time right... How can we avoid and workaround those... So trying to understand how they are working internally.

Comment: Maybe you face this issue when you are using both, but here you are having an ES6 module (given its usage of `import express from 'express';` - and it's even imported using ES6 in `import * as App from './server';`) that doesn't use `export` syntax as it should.